# Java - random "null" popping up during a Try/Catch

Tags: java

I have a script that tests the validity of characters entered in order to learn Try/Catch. The numbers must be entered in a strict "$123.45" format or else the Try/Catch prints an error. It needs to be able to catch all integer errors and print them. Currently, if a dollar AND a cent are entered incorrectly the script works fine and prints both errors. However, if ONLY an error is found when entering cents, the print line says begins with "null".

**Example (working):
Input:**
Please enter amount of sale in form $#.## ("q" to quit): $12d.de

**Print:**
Invalid dollar format - For input string: "12d"

Invalid cents format - For input string: "de"

**Example (NOT working):
Input:**
Please enter amount of sale in form $#.## ("q" to quit): $123.de

**Print:**
nullInvalid cents format - For input string: "de"

The error is in the "+=" in the Catch for myCent:

"myBad += "Invalid cents format - For input string: \"" + mySale.substring(mySale.indexOf('.') + 1,mySale.length()) + "\"\n";"

How do I get the Catch to not print "null" without losing the multi-error print functionality? Any and all help us GREATLY appreciated.

This program consists of the below two scripts, the "DKSaleCheck.java" is my problem child:
**DKUnit6Ch15.java**

```
import java.util.*; //Load all Utility Classes

public class DKUnit6Ch15 { //Begin Class DKUnit6Ch15

    public static void main(String[] args) { //Begin Main
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in); //Initialize the Scanner
        String myAmount; //Define a new Variable

        while(true) { //Begin infinite While Loop
            System.out.print("Please enter amount of sale in form $#.## (\"q\" to quit): "); //Print the text
            myAmount = myScan.next(); //Define a new Variable with the next user input

            if(myAmount.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) { //Begin If Statement (if the user entered "q" then do the following...)
                break; //Break the script
            } //End If Statement

            DKSaleCheck myCash = new DKSaleCheck(myAmount); //Define a new Variable and send it to the Constructor
            myCash.print(); //Print the Output from the Constructor
        } //End infinite While Loop

        myScan.close(); //Close the Scanner

    } //End Main

} //End Class DKUnit6Ch15
```

**DKSaleCheck.java**

```
    class DKSaleCheck{ //Begin Class DKSaleCheck

    int myDollar; //Define a new Variable
    int myCent; //Define a new Variable
    String myBad; //Define a new String Variable

    public DKSaleCheck(String mySale) { //Begin Method DKSaleCheck and receive sale as a string
        myBad = null; //Define a new Variable

        if(!mySale.startsWith("$")) { //Begin If Statement (if mySale does NOT start with a "$")
            myBad = "Invalid sale format missing \"$\" - " + mySale + "\n"; //Fill the Variable with the String data
        } //End If Statement

        else if(mySale.indexOf('.') == -1) { //Begin ElseIf Statement (if mySale does NOT contain a ".")
            myBad = "Invalid sale format missing \".\" - " + mySale + "\n"; //Fill the Variable with the String data
        } //End ElseIf Statement

        else{ //Begin Else Statement
            try{ //Begin Try Statement
                myDollar = Integer.parseInt(mySale.substring(1, mySale.indexOf('.'))); //Fill the Variable with the data if ONLY integers are detected from Index 1 to the "."
            } //End Try Statement

            catch(Exception myError) { //Begin Catch Statement (if the subString does not contain ONLY integers)
                myBad = "Invalid dollar format - For input string: \"" + mySale.substring(1,mySale.indexOf('.')) + "\"\n"; //Fill the Variable with the String data
            } //End Catch Statement

            try{ //Begin Try Statement
                myCent = Integer.parseInt(mySale.substring(mySale.indexOf('.') + 1,mySale.length())); //Fill the Variable with the data if ONLY integers are detected after the "."
            } //End Try Statement
            catch(Exception myError) { //Begin Catch Statement (if the subString does not contain ONLY integers)
                myBad += "Invalid cents format - For input string: \"" + mySale.substring(mySale.indexOf('.') + 1,mySale.length()) + "\"\n"; //Fill the Variable with the String data
            } //End Catch Statement
        } //End Else Statement

    } //End Method DKSaleCheck

    public void print(){ //Begin Print Method

        if(myBad != null){ //Begin If Statement (if the error variable is NOT null)
            System.out.println(myBad); //Print the String Variable     
        } //End If Statement

        else{ //Begin Else Statement
            System.out.println("$" + myDollar + "." + myCent); //Print the text
            System.out.println(myDollar + " dollars and " + myCent + " cents\n"); //Print the text
        } //End Else Statement

    } //End Print Method

} //End Class DKSaleCheck
```

Comment: You have `myBad +=` where you need `myBad =`. As it is initially null, you get a null.

Comment: But if I remove the "+" it will no longer find multiples. It ends after printing only the error with cents. For instance if I enter "$12d.de" it only shows the error in the cents part and not the dollar part.

Comment: Please, format the code. On debug you can see what exactly is null in your case.

Comment: One solution is to change `myBad = null;` to `myBad = ""; `

Comment: What multiples? You can only get one exception at a time.

Comment: Scary Wombat - Ah, ok. So I changed myBad = null; to myBad = ""; and then just had to change if(myBad != null) to if(myBad != "") and now it works perfectly. Man, it's the little syntax stuff like this that trips me up every time. Thanks a lot to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Scary Wombat had the best answer. I changed:

```
public DKSaleCheck(String mySale) {    
   myBad = null; 
   //rest of class
}

public void print(){ 
   if(myBad != null)
   //rest of class
}
```

to:

```
public DKSaleCheck(String mySale) {    
   myBad = ""; 
   //rest of class
}

public void print(){ 
   if(myBad != "")
   //rest of class
}
```

Worked like a champ!